# My-Sql JOIN two tables error

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I tried to combine two tables' data.

I got an error like this. can you see why?

> Every derived table must have its own alias

```
SELECT a.title, number 
FROM store a 
  JOIN 
  ( SELECT count(b.code) as number 
    FROM redeem_codes b 
    WHERE product = a.title 
      AND available = "Available")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have `ALIAS` on your subquery.

```
SELECT a.title, number 
FROM store a   
     JOIN (subquery) b -- b is the `ALIAS`
                       -- and this query will not give you the result you want
```

but here's a more efficient query without using subquery,

```
SELECT  a.title, count(b.code) number 
FROM    store a 
        INNER JOIN redeem_codes b             -- or use LEFT JOIN to show 0
                                              -- for those who have no product
            ON b.product = a.title
WHERE   b.available = 'Available'
GROUP BY    a.title
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard tell without knowing more about your table structures. I'll give a try anyway:

```
SELECT a.title, count(b.code) AS number FROM store a
LEFT JOIN redeem_codes b ON b.product = a.title
WHERE b.available = "Available"
GROUP BY a.title;
```